# Jquery AJAX Result data retrieve back to client side in velocity template

Tags: java, json, jquery, jira

I have just created an AJAX request in velocity template and able to get request at .java file as below: (java file is extended for "JiraWebActionSupport" as webwork module).

```
var url = "PlanIssuesAction!IssuesPlanning.jspa";
jQuery.post(url,myJSONObject,function(result) {
    alert('success');
})
.done(function() { alert("in done"); })
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
.always(function() { alert("finished"); });
```

On the server side, in `doIssuesPlanning` method, able to get call and insert the posted data.

```
 public String doIssuesPlanning() {
     System.out.println("Success executed result appear"); //i want this value to be //retrieval at client side but it's not working. unable to receive at ajax response. 
 return getRedirect("PlanIssuesAction!default.jspa");
```

//return "result is success" //also tried instead of getRedirect ,used direct response //return but not worked, it capture at error in ajax response at client side.
    }

Now I need to return the result data to the client side back at jquery "Result" parameter.

How can I achieve this? Currently, in "Result" object shows all HTML text and nothing else.
(i have set object above through - "System.out.println and expect to be retrieved at client side but not working).

Can you please let me know , what is wrong here.

Thank you.

Comment: Please let me know if need any more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webwork jspa URLs return HTML since that is their purpose. Most AJAX calls would be to a REST resource that returns JSON. I'd define a new REST resource for this. More information at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Developing+a+REST+Service+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I went through link. So, it looks like, i have to add - REST Service module into my jira plugin and create rest resource class "MyRestResource" where i should keep all my save, data retrieval methods. And then, use this service into webwork module - template vm file to call this service using JSON. Is it correct ? Please also let me know, how can i call this service from webwork - vm template file ?

Comment: Also, here, do i have to create another RefApp REST plugin and refer it's reference link in my JIRA Plugin or, I can use REST resource classes into same jira plugin project ?

Comment: I have created REST Resource Service by adding REST Module in my jira project, by follow below tutorial.

https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/REST+Plugin+Module

and able to make call to server side, REST Resource service url is compose as follow:

http://myhost.com:port/myapp/rest/api-name/api-version/resource-name
Just for reference, another ticket for related communication:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/156650/development-in-jira-plugin-how-to-use-rest-api-in-velocity-template-through-json
Thank You,

Dhaval Soni